# Integrating circles

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose I want to integrate a circle.

$$y^2 + (x-5)^2 = 5^2$$

To find the area of said circle, I'd pick my limits to be $0$ and $5$. However, this circle is on either side of the $x$-axis - what would happen if were to integrate this with respect to $x$? Would the answer be $0$?

Which leads me on to my next question: I know that the volume of a revolution is found by

$$\pi \int y^2 \,\mathrm{d}x.$$

So if I were to then integrate this circle by simply moving the $(x-5)^2$ term to the other side, would I get the volume of two circles?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.
I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the area of the circle in cartesian coordinates, you can integrate in either $x$ or $y$ and exploit symmetry as follows:
$$
A=2\int_0^{10}\sqrt{25-(x-5)^2}\mathrm dx
$$
which will require a trig substitution. Similarly,
$$
A=2\int_{-5}^5\sqrt{5^2-y^2}+5\mathrm dy
$$
which again requires a trig sub.

I don't know what you mean by the volume of two circles. However, if you compute the volume of revolution, you'll get, well, a volume. Specifically the volume of the sphere (if you set up the bounds correctly).

Comment: Hi - I may have confused in the question. What I mean is, from my understanding, integration gives the area between the curve and the axis, in this case the x axis. However, the equation of a circle yields curves both above and below the axis. When integrating the revolution, does this mean that both of those curves are rotated 360 degrees thus giving the volume of two spheres? Sorry if I'm being confusing here

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, $$y^2 + (x-5)^2 = 5^2 \implies  y=\pm \sqrt {5^2 -(x-5)^2}$$

The area of the circle is the area bounded by these two semicircles so you need to integrate  $$ \int _0^{10} 2\sqrt {5^2 -(x-5)^2}$$ to find the area of the circle.

Regarding your second question you are correct in in finding $y^2$ from your equation.